# Add a custom attribute to all existing users

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I already have a running Keycloak instance with a lot of registered users. How can I add a new custom attribute (with an empty value) to all users without doing it manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I add a new custom attribute (with an empty value) to all
> users without doing it manually?

You can use [Keycloak Rest Admin API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/5.0/rest-api/index.html):

First you use endpoint

```
GET /{realm}/users
```

to get all the users. Then for each user you extract its ID an call the endpoint :

```
PUT /{realm}/users/{id}
```

with the payload {"attributes": <old Attributes> + < new Attributes>}

I have create a bash script for this in [my repo](https://github.com/dreamcrash/StackOverflow-/blob/main/Keycloak/RestAdminAPI/Users/addAttributeToAllUsers.sh). Running example:

```
sh addAttributeToAllUsers.sh localhost:8080 admin admin test '{"c":["c"]}'
```